# Javascript - TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I am looping an array and constructing an array as below. While executing this code i am getting an error as

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of object
> '#'

```
const finalItems: any = [];
  data.items.forEach((parent: any) => {
    // parent construct
    parent.id = parent.productId;
    parent.level = parent.level;

    // remove other keys in json
    delete parent.links;

    finalItems.push({
      node: parent,
      key: parent.id,
    });
  });
return items;
```

I have tried to change the code as below looking into one of the link in stackoverflow, but it gives error as undefined is not a function

```
data.items.forEach((parent: any) => {
// parent construct
parent.id(parent.productId);
});
```

Can someone suggest on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `parent` is `readonly` so you can not modify it, you need to get copy from it like bellow code :

//options1

```
const finalItems: any = [];
data.items.forEach((parent: any) => {
  // parent construct
  const newParrent = parent;
  newParrent.id = parent.productId;
  newParrent.level = parent.level;

  // remove other keys in json
  delete newParrent.links;

  finalItems.push({
    node: newParrent,
    key: newParrent.id
  });
});
```

or use `map`

```
//option 2

const finalItems = data.items.map((parent) => {
  const newParrent = parent;
  newParrent.id = parent.productId;
  newParrent.level = parent.level;
  // remove other keys in json
  delete newParrent.links;

  return {
    node: newParrent,
    key: newParrent.id
  };
});
```

> note : this answer is just for guide and it is may not be the final answer